# Using 1Gbps internet connection with 10/100Mbps LAN Chip

Tags: internet, internet-connection, gigabit-ethernet

Would it be a problem if somebody subscribe for an 1Gb internet connection, but have 10/100Mbps LAN Chip in one of its computer? I have wondered as the provider's site shows 1Gb Card as a minimum requirements, i5/i7 processor, 4GB RAM, which are not an option on the computer.  Is it a problem which will not enable the computer to connect to the internet, or it will be "only" slower?

Comment: The provider side wouldn't have a minimum requirement NIC card for the subscriber. The person who installs the service may inform the subscriber about getting a newer NIC, but that's about it. The subscriber would simply be limited to 100 Mbps download speed.

Answer (score 3):

That wont be an issue the only downside is you wont be able to make use of its full potential.

Answer (score -1):

**It will be "only" slower**, if you want to put it that way.

However, what doesn't make sense here is buying a gigabit connection only to use it with a slow network card. Even then, sure, the computer will be able to connect to the network and browse at 100mbps, since the protocols are backward compatible.

However, as Ron Maupin has pointed out, it is possible that the equipment may not support slow speeds, but it is unlikely for consumer equipment.

Comment: The are only backward compatible in some circumstances. There are newer devices that do not support some of the slower speeds.

Comment: @Ron Maupin, can you cite a source? Also, in that case I wonder why the other answer is so upvoted

Comment: I have no idea about the votes, but I know, for instance, that some network devices, e.g. Cisco Nexus, no longer support 10 Mbps for some ports, or 10 and 100 Mbps for others. It is also not confined to Cisco. Something like this has come up before on [networkengineering.se].

Comment: @Ron Maupin, I have added an edit.